# Correcting entries in GUI while using threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I coded tkinter GUI, which have some entry fields and does some operations after clicking "Start" button. I had a problem with "No response" GUI windows crash while executing these operations. I also wanted to have a label in GUI which informs about current status of these operations, so I/ve decided to use threads. Now the problem is, that after clicking "Start" button, thread is created and in case of some exceptions (created to avoid input errors) I have no possibility to click it again because of 'threads can only be started once' error. I have tried to use .join() on thread in case of exception, but 'current thread cannot be joined'.

```py
import customtkinter
import threading
import tkinter

class MyGui:


    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

        self.entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.app, placeholder_text="Enter even number")
        self.entry_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.app, text="Start", command=threading.Thread(target=self.button_callback).start)
        self.button_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    def is_even(self):
        if int(self.entry_1.get()) % 2 != 0:
            raise ValueError("Not even number")
        else:
            print("Even indeed")

    def button_callback(self):
        try:
            self.is_even()
        except ValueError:
            return tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message") 

app = customtkinter.CTk()
running = MyGui(app)
app.mainloop()
```

I am not able to correct my input mistakes, because I can't run them anymore, I need to turn off/on my GUI in case to do that. Could tell me how to error thread or how to achieve my goal some other way?

Comment: Please reproduce your example minimally so that it can be analyzed correctly and easily, I recommend looking at some things about after, which does not cause multithreading problems and works well with tkinter...

[see minimal reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)


[see after](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/)

Comment: hi, example is edited : )

Answer (score 0):

I see that you must create a separate function, and call the command that can call it, it can be done in two ways, the first is with one more function inside your class

```py
import threading
import tkinter

import customtkinter


class MyGui:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

        self.entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.app,
                                              placeholder_text="Enter even number")
        self.entry_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.app, text="Start",
                                                command=self.start_thread)
        self.button_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    def start_thread(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.button_callback).start()

    def is_even(self):
        if int(self.entry_1.get()) % 2 != 0:
            raise ValueError("Not even number")
        else:
            print("Even indeed")

    def button_callback(self):
        try:
            self.is_even()
        except ValueError:
            return tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message")


app = customtkinter.CTk()
running = MyGui(app)
app.mainloop()
```

Or use an anonymous lambda function, but I don't particularly like this solution, it's very illegible, but it works

```py
command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.button_callback).start())
```